# Limiting Cognito User Pool user to single device

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to make an app that requires two kinds of authentication. A machine login and a user login, I'm using a custom authorizer to authenticate with the two and give access to my AWS resources

What I'm trying to do is the limit the machine login to only be logged in only in one device.

Currently I'm trying to get the list of remembered devices using the `cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminListDevices` API of Cognito User pool on **Pre Authentication** trigger of user pool. The problem is that on the event, AWS doesn't specify which device is currently trying to authenticate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently we don't support this use case, but we have heard customers request this feature. We will take this as +1 for feature request.

Comment: Ohh.. Thanks, I'll just create new accounts on new devices for now.